# How can I blur and dim an image to be used as an activity background?

Tags: android, image, blur

Like the title says: I want to blur and darken a downloaded image.
The `BlurMaskFilter` in the SDK sounds relevant, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used this once and just for fun (not an expert). Try something like:

```
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(20, Blur.OUTER));
```

for more there is a nice blog [here](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the BlurMaskFilter apparently only works on the alpha channel of pixels, so has no effect on solid image.